# Shiny downloadHandler does not save in .png format

Tags: r, save, png, shiny

I am having some trouble downloading .png graphs with Shiny using downloadHandler while I don't have difficulty with .pdf.

I would like to create some app in which the user download a data file and, in one of the many tabs, create some histograms; afterward the user can choose among different file formats to download the graphs (for instance .png and .pdf).

When I check the .pdf button the .pdf file pops up without a window asking to save the file; when the button .png is checked a windows pops up but the .png is not saved.

Here you can find the pieces of my code of interest:

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
server.r

output$down <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function(){
        paste("Histogram", input$downhist, sep =".")
      },
      content = function(file){
        if(input$downhist == "pdf")
          pdf(file)
        else
          png(file)


        hist(data()$SF)
        dev.off()
      }
    )

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
ui.r
...
      radioButtons(inputId = "downhist",
                   label = "4. Select the histogram file type",
                   choices = list("png", "pdf")),
...
```

For the rest my code works just fine.

I have read many posts about but I can't manage to find a solution. I can post more code if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that I should have used `Run External` when running the app. I don't know the technical reasons but the code now works like a charm.